# Set all quotes to double quote using C#

Tags: c#, double-quotes, quote

I try to make it possible for users to search for customers with a quote in the CustomerName.

The user search the user in the customerNameTextBox wich is set to the customerNameTB.

If the user uses a quote(') it will be replaced with a double-quote.

And if there is a triple quote(''') it will be replaced with a double-quote.

**Here is my code:**

```
string customerNameTB = customerNameTextbox.Text;                
customerNameTB.Replace("'", "''");                
while (customerNameTB.Contains("'''"))
{
   customerNameTB.Replace("'''", "''");
}
```

The result after this code is the quotes are still single quotes.

Whats is wrong with this little piece of code..

**Edit after answers**

My code should look like this:

```
 string customerNameTB = customerNameTextbox.Text;                
    customerNameTB = customerNameTB.Replace("'", "''");                
    while (customerNameTB.Contains("'''"))
    {
       customerNameTB = customerNameTB.Replace("'''", "''");
    }
```

Comment: I really hope this isn't then concatenated into a SQL query?  If it is, you should probably go and read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close! This is what you need:

```
string customerNameTB = customerNameTextbox.Text;  
// single quotes
customerNameTB = customerNameTB.Replace("'", "''");
// triple quotes
customerNameTB = customerNameTB.Replace("'''", "''");
```

The replace doesn't replace it in the original string, it returns a new string that you have to assign to something or it just gets thrown away.

Comment: You can also chain your Replace() too. Such as Replace().Replace() etc

Comment: @Darren Like this you mean? customerNameTB = customerNameTB.Replace("'", "''").Replace("'''", "''"); Even if so, I prefer the readability of the original personally.

Comment: - yep, that's what I mean. Sure, the split one is more readable. was just a comment that you can chain these string functions too :)

Answer (score 1):

String.Replace does not modify the string it is running on.
You need to assign the result of Replace to your string:

```
   string customerNameTB = customerNameTextbox.Text;                
   customerNameTB=customerNameTB.Replace("'", "''");                
   customerNameTB=customerNameTB.Replace("'''", "''");
```

Also, there is no need for a loop, since Replace replaces ALL occurrences of the search string.

Comment: The loop is for something that has say 6 single quotes in a row.  That would first replace the first 3 with 2 then the second 3 with 2 leaving 4.  The next loop would replace the first 3 with 2 leaving 3, then finally replacing the 3 with 2 on the final loop.  Now weather that is correct for what the OP wants is another question.